# Are there any other purposes for compiling IL

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, runtime, il, native-code

I'm pretty sure one reason for compiling down a high-level language into some bytecode is so the VM (Java or .NET) can generate machine dependent native instructions.

Is that the only reason? If there was some way (in theory) to generate machine dependent instructions before program execution (on different computers), would there be any purpose for compiling down to bytecode? Could we just compile down to machine code and execute those instructions at runtime?

To clear it up:

If the compiler could just generate perfect instructions for every computer, is IL needed?

Comment: So your question is: If the compiler could generate perfect instructions for every architecture straight away.. is IL needed?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, yes, exactly.

Comment: The other benefit of IL is language-independence. For example, I can use a .NET library written in VB and compile _against_ it with my C# projects. In addition, when compiling to be "perfect instructions" for a certain/every architecture, sometimes information is lost (such as method inlining) which otherwise should be available as a callable API.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Isn't more an advantage of common metadata format than IL itself? For example with WinRT, you can use library written in C++ from JavaScript, and neither language uses IL.

Comment: @svick: I suppose so though I don't know the details of how JavaScript or C++ compiles into assemblies. But again, if IL is skipped and you were to magically compile to native (likely optimized) machine code that inlined/reorganized/optimized/_things_ it seems to me that information is essentially lost. Also, IL provides a common base for other utilities to hook into (IL weaving for example) I guess really, the question is, what are the benefits of compiling to an intermediary, common state (in this case, a combination of metadata + IL) rather than directly to native optimized machine code.

Answer (score 1):

It **simplifies compilers**, because now we can target just one simple assembly language – CIL – rather than four or five complicated ones.

You must not take this benefit lightly. x64 assembly, as an extension of an extension of an extension of an 8-bit instruction set from almost four decades ago, is full of special cases and design flaws. CIL is magical unicorn rainbows in comparison.

It **eases development**, because we no longer need to set up convoluted cross-compilation toolchains just to build a phone app. A single library will work on both desktop and mobile, no recompilation required.

Yes, you *can* just bundle multiple versions of your code, one for each architecture, into a single file. [Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) did this in their PowerPC-to-Intel transition. But the resulting binaries are often large, which doesn't work well for mobile.

It **increases the scope for optimization**. Any optimizations in a AOT compiler only affect the code it compiles. But optimizations in a JIT will speed up *all* programs.

The JIT also has an extra source of information – the running program itself. By watching how the program runs, the JIT can target the areas of code that need it the most. The Java [HotSpot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) VM uses this technique extensively.

I think there are more advantages, but those are the obvious ones.

Answer (score 0):

CLR assemblies contain IL/MSIL/CIL/whatever the term *du jour* is these days. That is to make the compiled code hardware and operating system independent. So long as the target system supports the specified version of the CLR (and the code isn't doing anything funny with P/Invoke or the like), the assembly should run on the target system. When the assembly is loaded, it is JIT'd into native machine code (or you could `ngen` it to produce a machine specific binary.

The reason for having portable executables should be fairly obvious (which see Java).

Comment: My question was are there any advantages using this method other than producing machine independent instructions for the VM to interpret.

Comment: @ROK: the VM doesn't interpret anything. On loading the assembly into the app domain, the assembly is **compiled** into CPU-specific machine code. The advantage is portability (not to mention decompilability).

Comment: All of the IL is compiled into CPU-specific machine code? I thought that the IL is compiled only when it is needed to, and then cached for later use.

Answer (score 0):

So you're wondering why use an intermediate language at all?

Byte code (IL, Java byte code, even VB6's p-code) offers several advantageous. These come from the fact that the byte code is not immediately compiled and run on the target CPU. In IL's case, it is just in time compiled (JIT) to machine instructions on demand.

While this seems inherently more complicated than just compiling down to native code right away, we get a bunch of useful features from this, like reflection, garbage collection, type safety, and exception handling.

You could get those nice fancy managed features without IL by JITig C# code to native code, but then you'd have to implement those features and and write a JITer for each language you want (C++/CLI, VB.NET, etc.).

Additionally, it's much easier to write those managed features for a machine based language then try to write those features for a language that is primarily designed for human consumption.

Comment: 1. The desktop CLR never interprets CIL, so I'm not sure why are you listing that as a main advantage. 2. Neither reflection nor GC require intermediate language.

Comment: @svick http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime It says it JITs IL to native in the second sentence

Comment: But JIT and interpreting the code are different things. Interpreting means that you directly execute the IL without compiling it first.

Comment: @Svick I see you're point. I mixed words. By "interpreted and compiled down to" I meant JITing. thanks for catching that, I'll edit my answer

Comment: So you're wondering why use an intermediate language at all? No. I'm wondering are there any other benefits other than having a lower-level machine independent language for the VM to compile.

Comment: "reflection, garbage collection, type safety, and exception handling" -- GHC Haskell has all these things, and it's compiled straight to native code. These are the advantages of a *language runtime*, not bytecode.

Comment: @LambdaFairy: One advantage of using an IL-based VM with a JIT is that it allows programs to have a boundless amount of code that "might" be executed, depending upon various run-time conditions.  For example, for each value type `T` that is used as a generic type parameter for `List<T>`, .NET will produce a different set of compiled methods.  The number of different value types for which that will be necessary is typically pretty small, but there's no limit to the number of types that could be created.  Even if the only types in the universe were `int` and `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`...

Comment: ...there are an infinite number of nested combinations of those types, each of which could require a separate version of `List<T>`'s methods.  There's no way one could precompile all the methods that could be necessary, but a JIT compiler can compile the methods that turn out to be required.